# Unity Iap in-app-puchase 4.9.4 NoSuchMethodError 'initialize'

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I updated Unity Iap in-app-puchase 4.4.1 to 4.9.4. because billing version 4 -> 5.
Unity Editor Version is 2021.3.10f1
but I have Problem.
This is android log cat.

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='initialize' signature='(Landroid.app.Application;Lcom.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener;Z)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;`

and I found that here is problem
Code (CSharp):

`UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);`

If I use billing version 4, there is no bug, but if I use version 5, there is a bug.

more detail information is here :
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-iap-in-app-puchase-4-9-4-nosuchmethoderror-initialize.1504007/

I fixed OnPurchaseFailed

```
`public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product i, PurchaseFailureReason p)
{
    if (p == PurchaseFailureReason.PurchasingUnavailable)
    {
        // IAP may be disabled in device settings.
    }
}
public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product i, PurchaseFailureDescription p)
{
    RestoreButtonClick();


    Debug.Log(p.ToString());
    if (p.reason == PurchaseFailureReason.DuplicateTransaction)
    {
        try
        {
            ResetrTransaction();
        }
        catch....................................`
```